# Why authentication works in some browsers but not in others

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

My app is on Azure AD and I'm using the following code to request authentication on the Auth Service:

HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home/Index" }, WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

What happens is that this works in some browsers (there is no pattern) and sometimes it doesn't work in others.

When the application redirects to /home/index, sometimes the object User.Identity has the user's email but sometimes it has no information.

Why is this happening?

Comment: In your question you are missing the code that you are using to extract email. Are you just using the standard `@User.Identity.Name` in your view? Is Whats' the state of `Request.IsAuthenticated`? Maybe you have an error handler swallowing the error?

Comment: So which browsers does it always work in and which browsers does it sometimes work in? Any pattern around private browsing? You r question doesn't indicate a lot of analysis

Answer (score 1):

Seamless SSO doesn't work in private browsing mode on Firefox and Microsoft Edge browsers. It also doesn't work on Internet Explorer if the browser is running in Enhanced Protected mode.

For SSO implementation , please consider browser consideration doc published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start#browser-considerations)

As per last update , here is supporting browser list

**Mozilla Firefox (all platforms)**

Mozilla Firefox doesn't automatically use Kerberos authentication. Each user must manually add the Azure AD URL to their Firefox settings by using the following steps:

- Run Firefox and enter about:config in the address bar. Dismiss any notifications that you see.
- Search for the network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris preference. This preference lists - - Firefox's trusted sites for Kerberos authentication.
- Right-click and select Modify.
  Enter https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com in the field.
- Select OK and then reopen the browser.

**Safari (macOS)**

Ensure that the machine running the macOS is joined to AD. Instructions for AD-joining your macOS device is outside the scope of this article.

**Google Chrome (all platforms)**

If you have overridden the AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist or the AuthServerWhitelist policy settings in your environment, ensure that you add Azure AD's URL (https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com) to them as well.

**Google Chrome (macOS and other non-Windows platforms)**

For Google Chrome on Mac OS and other non-Windows platforms, refer to The Chromium Project Policy List for information on how to whitelist the Azure AD URL for integrated authentication.

The use of third-party Active Directory Group Policy extensions to roll out the Azure AD URL to Firefox and Google Chrome on Mac users is outside the scope of this article.

Hope it helps.